# how to disable save option for fpdf generated files in php?

Tags: php, report, fpdf

i am using fpdf to generate reports in php. I don't want users to save the generated pdfs. They will only print the documents.How can i do it?Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure as long as this is sent to the client's browser from the server to display the pdf there is honestly nothing you can really do to prevent a user from "saving" it, they'll find a way.

Comment: but i need to do it for security purpose.There must be something to stop at least average users from saving it.

Comment: If you're allowing them to print the pdf, my understanding is that it will have to be saved as well. The closest thing I found that may help you protect your PDF is this [add-on](http://fpdf.de/downloads/addons/37/) but it prevents printing so I honestly don't think there is a real solution.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to prevent users from saving the PDF is the same as trying to prevent users from creating screenshots, they always find a work around. Also to be able to print PDF, the PDF has to be stored in the users cache to send it to their printer. Also some browsers cannot show the PDF with the option to print it, they have to download the PDF to open it in ie Adobe Reader to print it from there.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest not to create PDF for this, otherwise if PDF will be opened at browser that can be easily saved or copied. If you allow users to download it then make a copy of report in PDF and let client download it.

Comment: i can't let users download it.

Comment: Then take my first suggestion.

Comment: You can use report maker.

Comment: can you give me some links